# Laravel app displays wrong image source when deployed

Tags: laravel, cpanel, web-deployment

My app works perfectly offline but when deployed, I didn't get to display images properly.

this is my store controller function

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $contestant = new Contestant();
    $contestant->name = $request->name;
    $contestant->gender = $request->Gender[0];
    $contestant->Occupation = $request->Occupation;
    $contestant->Hobbies = $request->Hobbies;
    $contestant->DOB = $request->DOB;
    $contestant->Nationality = $request->Nationality;
    $contestant->location = $request->location;
    $contestant->About = $request->About;
    $contestant->votes = 0;
    $image = $request->photo;
    $imagePath = $image->store('contestant', 'public');
    $contestant->image = $imagePath;
    // Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
    // $contestant -> image = $imagePath;
    $contestant->save();
    return view('admin.home');
}
```

this is is how I display it in my blade

```html
<a class="cardlink" href="{{ route('Contestant.index',$contestant -> id)}}">
  <img class=" card-img-top " src="/storage/{{ $contestant -> image }}" alt="Card image cap">
</a>
```

EDIT

html code:

```
@foreach ($contestants as $contestant)
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card shadow contestant-card">
        <a class="cardlink" href="{{ route('Contestant.index',$contestant -> id)}}">
            <img class=" card-img-top " src="/storage/{{ $contestant -> image }}" alt="Card image cap"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-3"> <span class="text-dark"> Name:
                </span><br>{{ $contestant -> name }}
                {{-- <a href="#"
                    class="float-right d-inline-flex share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt text-primary"></i></a> --}}
            </h5>
            <p>
                <span class="card-text">{{ $contestant -> Ocupation ?? $contestant -> gender }}</span> |
                <span class="card-text"> {{ $contestant -> location }}.</span>
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $contestant -> id }}">
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
                class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Vote</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Vote for
                                {{ $contestant -> name }}</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            @csrf
                            @method('POST')
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">contestant Name: </label>
                                <input id="cc-pament" name="cc-payment" type="text" class="form-control"
                                    disabled value="{{ $contestant -> name }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="vote" class="control-label mb-1">Number of Votes: </label>
                                <select name="cc-vote" id="cc-vote" class="form-control"> Number of Votes
                                    <option value="none" selected disabled> Select</option>
                                    <option value="50">1 Vote for ₦50</option>
                                    <option value="3000">20 Votes for ₦3000</option>
                                    <option value="5000">40 Votes for ₦5000</option>
                                    <option value="10000">100 Votes for ₦10,000</option>
                                    <option value="20000">250 Votes for ₦20,000</option>
                                    <option value="40000">550 Votes for ₦40,000</option>
                                    <option value="100000">1,200 Votes for ₦100,000</option>
                                    <option value="200000">2,500 Votes for ₦200,000</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group has-success">
                                <label for="cc-name" class="control-label mb-1">Name</label>
                                <input id="cc-name" name="cc-name" type="text" class="form-control cc-name">
                                <span class="help-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="cc-name"
                                    data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <form action="{{ route('pay') }}" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="otemuyiwca@gmail.com">
                                    {{-- required --}}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="orderID" value="345">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="metadata"
                                        value="{{ json_encode($array = ['id' => $contestant -> id,]) }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="reference"
                                        value="{{ Unicodeveloper\Paystack\Facades\Paystack::genTranxRef() }}">
                                    {{-- required --}}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ config('paystack.secretKey') }}">
                                    {{-- required --}}
                                    {{ csrf_field() }} {{-- works only when using laravel 5.1, 5.2 --}}
                                    <button id="payment-button" type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
                                        <span id="payment-button-amount">Pay</span>
                                        <span id="payment-button-sending" style="display:none;">Sending…</span>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image is stored as `contestant/dgfy563tgfFTjhhyyf6CTiihiDc5tCT.jpeg` in my database but gives a broken image when displayed, when I inspect element with chrome, `img` src is `"/storage//tmp/phptYYEv9`

Comment: Are you deploying to shared hosting? are the `image/intervention` code lines commented on the deployed code too? Are you sure the `$contestant->image` property column has a correct image path in the database? try running artisan tinker to find out

Comment: I comment the intervention cos it's throwing a 500 server error,  there is a climb in the database that stores current link

Comment: Please edit the question and add the HTML form you're using to post this data